# Why kafka avro serializer is faster than json\string?

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, avro

How it's possible that avro serializer is faster than json(or string) serializers for objects/strings?

For example, if I am right, String serializer calls javaObject.toString() and then convert string to byte[], avro has same json-similar format, so it creates similar string and than convert to bytes[]?

Is it the same if you send already prepared String?

I expect than avro serializer is slightly better for objects and the same for strings. But everyone says avro is much better for objects. I'm Reading Apache Kafka book Todd Palino but there is zero info about it.

Answer (score 1):

> avro has same json-similar format

It does not. Binary Avro is not the same as its schema definition in JSON.

Avro is not converted to a string at any point, therefore is more compact than JSON (no quotes, colons, spaces, brackets, etc). The Avro API uses `BinaryEncoder` and a `ByteBuffer` object to build the `byte[]`.

This post may highlight some differences in JSON and other formats - https://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/12/05/schema-evolution-in-avro-protocol-buffers-thrift.html

Protobuf, Flatbuffers, JSON-smile, Captn-Proto, etc are all more effcient to build/parse as `byte[]` than raw JSON (or any) strings.